# Objective-C Check if two objects collide

Tags: objective-c, cgrect

I'm doing a lot of things now when I'm learning to programing in Objective-C.
I want now to check, if two object have meet. If their positions are the same.
I have done this with this:

```
 if(CGRectIntersectsRect(picture1.frame, picture2.frame))
```

But that is not the best solution, because my pictures are transparent (.png), but the picture inside is smaller and the shape of picture is not a square. So there are a lot of pixels around which I don't want to be part of this picture.

Is there a way to write like picture.frame-30 or something? Or someone have a better solution?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE`. Just because you are using the `xcode IDE` to do your development doesn't mean you should use the `xcode` tag. Please don't use it.

Comment: Doesn't CGRectInset(rect, dx, dy) work for you?

Comment: @Popeye Sorry. New  here. Wont do it again.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist CGREctlnset? Do you have an example?

Comment: Can you select quite enough bounary points of the picture and check if any of these points is inside the rect by using CGRectContainsPoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make "picture.frame - 30" object like this:

```
CGRect rect = picture2.frame;
CGRect innerPicture2Frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x+30, rect.origin.y+30, rect.size.width-60, rect.size.height-60);
```

Comment: Why not just use `CGRectInset`, which does this for you?

Comment: Yes, you are right for sure. I just have never used this and hence dunno what exactly this function does =)